A quick question on equivalence between cellular and singular homology
We know that for a CW complex $X$, the cellular and singular homology groups are isomorphic: $H_n (X) \cong H_n ^{CW} (X)$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$. My question is the following: suppose $Y$ is also a CW complex and $f: X \to Y$ is a cellular map. Does the induced diagram commute?
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
H_n (X) @>f_*>> H_n (Y)\\
@V{\cong}VV @VV{\cong}V\\
H_n^{CW} (X) @>>{f_*}> H_n ^{CW} (Y)
\end{CD}
This would make a ton of sense, since it would imply that singular and cellular homology functors are equivalent. However, I couldn't find a proof of this anywhere. Any help is greatly appreciated.
Edit: This used to be my attempt at solution, which didn't work due to a comment by @KritikerderElche.

Do you know how the proof of the isomorphism goes? One more thing you need is the cellular approximation theorem.

@MoisheKohan I know Hatcher's proof, yes. Unfortunately I don't see how cellular approximation would help. Could you maybe elaborate a little?

In your edit you have a typo. It should be $\cdots \to H_{n + 1} (X^{n + 1},X^n) \xrightarrow{d_{n+1}} H_{n} (X^n,X^{n-1}) \xrightarrow{d_n} H_{n - 1}(X^{n - 1},X^{n-2}) \to \dots$. And unfortunately $H_n(X^n) \to H^{CW}_n(X)$ is not an isomorphism, but only an epimorphism.

But if you look at Paul Frost's diagram, it suffices to show that $f_* : H_n(X^n) \to H_n(Y^n)$ maps $im \partial^X_{n+1}$ to $im \partial^Y_{n+1}$. This should be easy. Anyway, I do not think that one should edit a question by giving an answer. It is better to write an additional official  answer.

@KritikerderElche Yeah you're right, this doesn't work. I'll delete the edit.

The diagram commutes.
Hatcher does not define induced homomorphisms $f_* : H_n(X) \to H_n(Y)$ for cellular maps $f : X  \to Y$, but it clear from the naturality properties of singular homology that $f$ induces a chain map from the cellular chain complex of $X$ to that of $Y$ (see the diagram on p.139). That is, we indeed obtain an induced homomorphism $f_* : H_n(X) \to H_n(Y)$.
More precisely, we get homology functors from the category $\mathbf{CW}$ of CW-complexes and cellular maps to the category of abelian groups.
To prove that your diagram commutes, you have to understand what the isomorphism $H^{CW}_n(X) \to H_n(X)$ looks like (see Hatcher's Theorem 2.35). Cosnsider the following inclusion induced homomophisms:
$$\iota_n : H_n(X^{n+1}) \to H_n(X)$$
$$\kappa_n : H_n(X^n) \to H_n(X^{n+1})$$
$$i_n : H_n(X^n) \to H_n(X)$$
Hatcher shows that $\kappa_n$ induces an isomorphism
$$\kappa'_n : H_n(X^n)/\operatorname{im} \partial_{n+1} \to H_n(X^{n+1}) .$$
Since $\iota_n$ is an isomorphism by Lemma 2.34 and $i_n = \iota_n \circ \kappa_n$, we see that $i_n$ induces an isomorphism
$$i'_n : H_n(X^n)/\operatorname{im} \partial_{n+1} \to H_n(X) .$$
Hatchers also shows that $j_n$ induces an isomorphism
$$j'_n : H_n(X^n)/\operatorname{im} \partial_{n+1} \to \ker d_n/\operatorname{im} d_{n+1} = H^{CW}_n(X) .$$
But clearly the diagram
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
H_n(X) @<{i'_n}<< H_n(X^n)/\operatorname{im} \partial_{n+1} @>{j'_n}>> H^{CW}_n(X) \\
@V{f_*}VV @V{f_*}VV @V{f_*}VV \\
H_n(Y) @<<{i'_n}< H_n(Y^n)/\operatorname{im} \partial_{n+1} @>>{j'_n}> H^{CW}_n(Y)
\end{CD}
commutes by the naturality of singular homology.
Note that singular and cellular homology functors are not equivalent simply because they live on different categories: Cellular
homology on $\mathbf{CW}$ and singular homology on the category
$\mathbf{Top}$ of topological spaces and continuous maps.
However, there is a forgetful functor $V : \mathbf{CW} \to \mathbf{Top}$ (which forgets the CW-structures) and then we see that the functors $H^{CW}_n$ and $H_n \circ V$ are naturally isomorphic.
